# Splitting string to an unknown number of columns with HTML tags

Tags: php, html, string, split

Currently I receive a string of content with all type of html tags.

I'm wondering of a way to split them into several columns maintaining the HTML tags but don't allow to go after 600 characters.

I have the following :

```
$formatedContent = strip_tags($content, '<br><br/><strong><a><ul><li>');
$pages_array = explode(" ",$formatedContent);
$pages_array_split = array();
$letter_count = 0;
$split_start = 0;
foreach($pages_array as $key => $page) {
    if($letter_count+strlen($page)+1 > 600) {
        $split_point = $letter_count+strlen($page)+1;
        array_push($pages_array_split,substr($formatedContent,$split_start,$split_point));
        $split_start += $letter_count+strlen($page)+1;
        $letter_count = 0;
    } else if($key == count($pages_array)-1) {
        array_push($pages_array_split,substr($formatedContent,$split_start));
    }
    $letter_count += strlen($page)+1;
}
```

The `$content` var is the string with the content.

Right now I have some problems with this.

**1)** Sometimes the words are broken in the middle (because I have tags in the middle)

**2)** If I have a list in one column the next column is kinda destroyed because the `<li>` are not inside an `<ul>`

Is there a way to close the tags and open in the next column ? Is there a way to guarantee that the words won't be broken ?

### EDIT 1:

Input example:

```
<p><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum<br /></span>&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><br />Lorem ipsum ipsum<br /><br /></span></strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum ipsum</p>
<ul>
<li><span">Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
<li><span">Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
<li><span">Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>

<!--Imagine 600 characters till here and it breaks now!-->
<li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
<li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
<li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum.</span></li>
<li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
<li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum<br />&nbsp;<br /><br /></span></li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum ipsum</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum ipsum<a href="http://www.lorem.org/">www.lorem.org</a><a title="www.lorem.org" href="http://www.lorem.org/">/</a>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Then the output would be:

```
<div class="col"> //First column
   <p>
      <span>Lorem ipsum ipsum<br /></span><br />
      <strong>
         <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><br />Lorem ipsum ipsum<br /><br /></span>
      </strong>
   </p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum ipsum</p>
   <ul>
     <li><span">Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
     <li><span">Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
     <li><span">Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<!--Imagine 600 characters till here and it breaks now!-->
<div class="col"> //Second column
    <ul>
        <li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
        <li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
        <li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum.</span></li>
        <li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum</span></li>
        <li><span>Lorem ipsum ipsum<br />&nbsp;<br /><br /></span></li>
    </ul>
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum ipsum</strong></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ipsum<a href="http://www.lorem.org/">www.lorem.org</a><a title="www.lorem.org" href="http://www.lorem.org/">/</a>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

And it continues for the rest of the columns.
 
Is this possible ? 
If it's too much of code to do can you tell me what approach I should take ?

Comment: Can you show sample input & output and also what output you hoped for?

Comment: can you explain me the idea behind $split_point = $letter_count+strlen($page)+1; ? Please share an example

Comment: @stvcisco added the example input & output

Comment: @ArturPeniche the ideia is to check if the char length will be > 600 and if it is i don't push the last word to the array

Comment: You would need to keep track of nesting states. For example, if you have a break in the middle of a `<ul>` your code would have to know it hasn't closed that yet, add a closing `</ul>` before the next `<li>` and restart the list in the next column.  This could get tricky if you allow nested lists or other complex structures. You may also have to worry about other multi-line constructs like `<ol>`, `<pre>` and `<dl>`. Even a `<a>` section could be split and would have to be handled in some meaningful way. Seems like a ton of work.

Comment: @stvcisco thanks for that. yeah, seems a ton of work. do you think I could take another approach on it?

Comment: It would help to understand the higher level purpose of dividing the html into 'columns'.  What's the reason for this and why 600?

Comment: In the current html layout there is a section that has pagination inside a box. And the output can only be 600 chars max per column.

Comment: I guess you could detect the start of a block that you wouldn't want to split (like `<a>`) and first check if it would cross the 600 boundary. If so, split it before that tag and continue. For more complex structures like lists that can be broken, you'd have to keep track of nested constructs and do the appropriate close/restart code between columns. Basically you have to start parsing html.  I'm not sure how `<div>` tags would be handled though.  Could get messy.

Comment: gonna try it. i don't need to worry about the `div` tags inside. there isn't any.